# My App won't be shown in the Google Analytics Live View

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

My App won't show up in the Google Analytics Live View, even after waiting up to 10 minutes.
However, if I use the property ID of another app I made, it works.
Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For live view you need to install signed apk with same key.Then it will work with analytic.

Because some time its not working with unsigned apk.

I hope it work.

Comment: Yogendra, Google Analytics doesn't require or check if the app is signed. This was not the cause. For a new property sometimes it takes up to 24h to start seeing real time data.